# How to make MDL tables responsive?

Tags: material-design-lite

For [MDL tables](http://www.getmdl.io/components/index.html#tables-section), is there an attribute to make the table responsive?

Answer (score 10):

To make a material design lite table responsive, you can use the same principle of the `.table-responsive` class of bootstrap.The table will then scroll horizontally on small devices (under 768px). When viewing on anything larger than 768px wide, there is no difference.

If you don't want to include the entire bootstrap library, include the following CSS in your project:

```
.table-responsive {
    min-height: .01%;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .table-responsive {
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
    }
    .table-responsive > .table {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    .table-responsive > .table > thead > tr > th,
    .table-responsive > .table > tbody > tr > th,
    .table-responsive > .table > tfoot > tr > th,
    .table-responsive > .table > thead > tr > td,
    .table-responsive > .table > tbody > tr > td,
    .table-responsive > .table > tfoot > tr > td {
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    .table-responsive > .table-bordered {
        border: 0;
    }
    .table-responsive > .table-bordered > thead > tr > th:first-child,
    .table-responsive > .table-bordered > tbody > tr > th:first-child,
    .table-responsive > .table-bordered > tfoot > tr > th:first-child,
    .table-responsive > .table-bordered > thead > tr > td:first-child,
    .table-responsive > .table-bordered > tbody > tr > td:first-child,
    .table-responsive > .table-bordered > tfoot > tr > td:first-child {
        border-left: 0;
    }
    .table-responsive > .table-bordered > thead > tr > th:last-child,
    .table-responsive > .table-bordered > tbody > tr > th:last-child,
    .table-responsive > .table-bordered > tfoot > tr > th:last-child,
    .table-responsive > .table-bordered > thead > tr > td:last-child,
    .table-responsive > .table-bordered > tbody > tr > td:last-child,
    .table-responsive > .table-bordered > tfoot > tr > td:last-child {
        border-right: 0;
    }
    .table-responsive > .table-bordered > tbody > tr:last-child > th,
    .table-responsive > .table-bordered > tfoot > tr:last-child > th,
    .table-responsive > .table-bordered > tbody > tr:last-child > td,
    .table-responsive > .table-bordered > tfoot > tr:last-child > td {
        border-bottom: 0;
    }
}
```

And then, just wrap the material design table inside a div tag with the `.table-responsive` class:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="mdl-data-table mdl-data-table--selectable mdl-shadow--2dp" style="margin: 0 auto;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Property</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Description</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">single</td>
            <td>Function</td>
            <td>Start the single file picker.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">multi</td>
            <td>Function</td>
            <td>Start the multi file picker.</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

That should create the following table in a small device:

[image: Responsive table bootstrap material design]

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```css
.mdl-data-table {
    table-layout:fixed;
    width:100%; 
}
#my-table td, th {
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

/* unrelated to responsive table css */
#my-table{
  margin-top:24px;
}
.material-icons {
  vertical-align: -25%;
}
```

```html
<meta name="description" content="Responsive Material Design Lite Table" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.green-light_green.min.css" />
<script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.min.js"></script>

<section class="mdl-grid" id="my-table">
  <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
  <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col-tablet mdl-cell--10-col-desktop mdl-cell--stretch">

    <table class="mdl-data-table mdl-js-data-table mdl-shadow--2dp">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Key</th>
          <th>Description</th>
          <th>Run</th>
          <th><i class="material-icons">timer</i></th>
          <th>Work</th>
          <th><i class="material-icons">timer</i></th>
          <th>Play</th>
          <th><i class="material-icons">timer</i></th>
          <th>Study</th>
          <th><i class="material-icons">timer</i></th>
          <th>Assumptions</th>
          <th>Climb Mountain</th>
          <th>Fly Kite</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>ABC-1234</td>
          <td>asdf asdf asdf asdf</td>
          <td>asdf asdf asdf asdf</td>
          <td>25</td>
          <td>qwer qwer qwer</td>
          <td>25</td>
          <td>sdfgs sdf sdgf</td>
          <td>25</td>
          <td>lkjhlk lkhjh</td>
          <td>25</td>
          <td>bvnfhf hffjj hdgdh</td>
          <td>25</td>
          <td>bjh jbh kjb bkjb</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>XYZ-1234</td>
          <td>dfdf asdf asdf asdf</td>
          <td>bgbgdf asdf asdf asdf</td>
          <td>25</td>
          <td>qwer qwer qwer</td>
          <td>25</td>
          <td>sdfgs sdf sdgf</td>
          <td>25</td>
          <td>lkjhlk lkhjh</td>
          <td>25</td>
          <td>bvnfhf hffjj hdgdh</td>
          <td>25</td>
          <td>bjh jbh kjb bkjb</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use bootstrap in addition to MDL (Material Design Lite). Using bootstrap, a table can be made responsive using: `<div class="table-responsive"> </div>` The MDL table can be added within the div elements.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you get around this one ?

Comment: Yes, as mentioned above by using both Bootstrap and MDL. So the MDL table goes between `<div class="table-responsive"> </div>`.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem so, I can figure it out this way

```
  <div class="table-responsive mdl-shadow--4dp">
   <table class="mdl-data-table mdl-js-data-table">
    <thead>
     <tr>
      <th  class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Material</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Unit price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td  class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Dore</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>$2.90</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td  class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Window</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>$1.50</td>
   </tr>  
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

I gave the mdl table a class of:

```
table {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```