# Material design table not displaying full width Angular2

Tags: angular, material-design

Hello I have a simple angular application which displays the following when the component loads

[image]

The table for some reason is not displaying full width inside the left panel

template code is as follows

```
<div class="demo-graphs mdl-shadow--2dp mdl-color--white mdl-cell mdl-cell--8-col">
      <h3>Tasks Page    
      <table class="mdl-data-table mdl-js-data-table mdl-data-table--selectable mdl-shadow--2dp full-width">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric full-width">Material</th>
              <th>Quantity</th>
              <th>Unit price</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Acrylic (Transparent)</td>
              <td>25</td>
              <td>$2.90</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Plywood (Birch)</td>
              <td>50</td>
              <td>$1.25</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Laminate (Gold on Blue)</td>
              <td>10</td>
              <td>$2.35</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>
</div>
```

Any ideas how I can display the table full width ?

Comment: could you create your problem on plunker ?

Comment: plunkr -  https://plnkr.co/edit/syTYmhFRX4cPDPk49wDF?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change this line with

```
<table class="mdl-data-table mdl-js-data-table mdl-data-table--selectable mdl-shadow--2dp full-width">
```

with

```
<table class="mdl-data-table mdl-js-data-table mdl-data-table--selectable mdl-shadow--2dp full-width" style='width:100%'>
```

try this one with `col-12`

```
<div class="demo-graphs  mdl-color--white mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col">
```

<kbd>[Updated Working Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/fx60RYnAcZRimTcteBrp?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: This apparently is not responsive.. the table is displaying only partially on the phone.

Comment: check this one my Update @user2180794

Comment: didn't work .. it pushes the datacards to the bottom

Comment: In the screenshot, I didn't add it to plunker.

Comment: than you have to add this to the plunker, the code you given to me i resolve the issue

Comment: This is an issue with the material design table itself. It is not responsive. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32317740/how-to-make-mdl-tables-responsive